# React how apply height adjustment between section B and C like section A and B width adjustment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here is my react code. Currently, I can adjust the width between Sections A and B depending on house movement. Now I like a similar feature BUT it will be for width adjustment between only sections B and C and will not change the height of section A. How?
[image]

```
const admin = () => {
  const [columnWidth, setColumnWidth] = useState(20); // Starting width percentage for column A
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const handleRef = useRef(null);

  const onMouseDown = () => {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  };

  const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return;

    // Calculate the percentage width of column A
    const containerRect = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const newWidth =
      ((e.clientX - containerRect.left) / containerRect.width) * 100;

    // Update the state with the new width, making sure it stays within bounds
    setColumnWidth(Math.min(100, Math.max(0, newWidth)));
  };

  const onMouseUp = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  };

  return (
    <>
<div
        ref={containerRef}
        style={{ display: "flex", height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            width: `${columnWidth}%`,
            background: "lightgrey",
            overflow: "auto", // Enable scrollbar when content exceeds height
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ height: "500px", padding: "16px" }}>Column A</div>
        </div>
        <div
          ref={handleRef}
          onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
          style={{ cursor: "ew-resize", width: "10px", background: "grey" }}
        />
        <div
          style={{
            width: `${100 - columnWidth}%`,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              background: "lightblue",
              overflow: "auto", // Enable scrollbar when content exceeds height
              flex: "70%", // 70% of the available space
            }}
          >
            <div style={{ height: "300px", padding: "16px" }}>Section B</div>
          </div>
          <div
            style={{
              background: "lightgreen",
              height: "30%", // 30% of the available space
              overflow: "auto", // Enable scrollbar when content exceeds height
            }}
          >
            Section C
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```